# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry error (not on compilation, but runtime)

Tags: java, hibernate

I must start by saying this is the first time I am using hibernate.
The error I am getting seems like a compilation failure, although I have both `hibernate-core` and `mysql-connector-j` as dependencies.

The way I initiate my session factory is the following:

```
        Configuration config = new Configuration();

        DBDetails details = DBDetails.fromConfig(lib);

        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url",
                "jdbc:mysql://" + details.getHost() + ":" + details.getPort() + "/" + details.getDatabase());
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", details.getUsername());
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", details.getPassword());
        config.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.pool_size", "1");

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();

        this.sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

I have this `Vote` class that is declared in the following way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "votes")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Vote {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "voter")
    private UUID voter;

    @Column(name = "voted")
    private UUID voted;
}
```

I am saving and retrieving vote info with the transaction methods that I've found online:

```
public void addVote(Vote vote) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(vote);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public Vote getVote(String voter) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Vote vote = session.get(Vote.class, voter);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return vote;
    }
```

I am getting a NoClassDefFoundError when running the .jar client-side (compilation works fine).

Any ideas on how to fix it and whether or not I must do anything to make the code functional afterwards?

Comment: I've figured out (my silly brain took long enough) that I need to shade in the JAR. How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "shade in the JAR"? What package manager are you using for dependencies? I could be that the dependency jar is not being included in the final jar file

Comment: I ain't using any package managers, just regular maven compilation. By shade into the jar I mean add the hibernate lib to my jar when compiling.

Comment: ChatGPT helped me figure out that I was compiling with Java 8 and hibernate needs at least java 11. After switching to Java 11 now my code does not compile anymore.